# Death Star 10188 Help with step 8 on page 76

Tags: technic

On step 8 of page 76 I do not understand what holds the two sections together.  The "LEGO Flat Silver Technic Axle Joiner Perpendicular with Extension (53586)" has a smooth bore where it attaches to the "LEGO Medium Stone Gray Technic Cross Block 1 x 3 (Pin/Pin/Pin) with 4 Pins (48989)".  And directly under the first part is a Technic pin (part# 4211815) in yet another smooth bore opening (part# 4526985).

I do not see any clips, pins or other means of attaching these two components.
[image: instruction page]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The "LEGO Flat Silver Technic Axle Joiner Perpendicular with Extension (53586)" smooth bore piece  is secured to a technic pin on piece "Technic, Pin Connector Perpendicular 3L with 4 Pins (48989)" installed in step 5, with the relevant pin marked in step 7 in my marked up directions below:

[image]

The smooth bore piece connects to the pin holding them together, with the lower axle connection preventing rotation.

Comment: The pin (4211887) in step 7 does not pass all the way through the other side of the 4 pin technic part (4225033)  if it did it would only collide with the end of the axle (4508553 from Step 8 item 4) inserted into the oposite end of 4494486.  The integrated pin on 4225033 slides in and out of the open end of 4494486, there aren't any internal ridges for the pin to snap into (hence the smooth bore description).  Do I have a bad 4494486?  I've looked online and every image I've been able to find of that part shows a smooth bore.  So I'm not sure what's the problem.

Comment: Even without the retaining ridge the pin should still be a tight friction fit against the smooth bore. it will come off if pulled, but it shouldn't just fall off.

Comment: Unfortunately it freely slides on and off [falls off], not even remotely tight - and I've tried ordering a replacement 4494486 from an online retailer with the same result.  I guess I'm just going to glue it.